# How can I emit a signal of another instance from _clicked() event?

Tags: c++, multithreading, qt, signals, slot

the runnable project is here:
[enter link description here](https://o365kw-my.sharepoint.com/:u:/g/personal/sinwoo_yoo_office_kw_ac_kr/EWh23q2yugZPm5y1Wn0DUwQBnoDeYBS-M7QRu_EWvSM1hg?e=rk917u)

---

I sincerely glad to have your detail answers to solve this, but I am still confusing on this issue:

case 1: changing `socket_session` as a member variable of mainwindow

```
class MainWindow : public QMainWindow
{
    Q_OBJECT

public:
    explicit MainWindow(QWidget *parent = 0);
    ~MainWindow();

    SocketThread* socket_session;

private:
...
```

But this is not the solution to access `setFlag`, even after I change the `Form1::on_qpushButton__set_white_level_0_clicked()' function like this:

```
void Form1::on_qpushButton__set_white_level_0_clicked() {
    qDebug() <<"clicked()";
    socket_session->setThreadFlag(true);

}
```

Still it doesn't make sense because `form1` instance doesn't have "the" instance of `socket_thread` which has been instantiated from `mainwindow`.
There's a solution I think is making another class that includes all instances that I want to use from inside of `mainwindow` but I don't think that is a good one because I am using thread and accessing a global big instance class that includes all of them to be "shared" is not a good idea for someone like me.

```
#include <form1.h>
#include <ui_form1.h>
#include "socketthread.h"


Form1::Form1(QWidget *parent) :
    QWidget(parent),
    ui(new Ui::Form1) {

    ui->setupUi(this);
}

Form1::~Form1() {
    delete ui;
}

void Form1::on_qpushButton__set_white_level_0_clicked() {
    qDebug() <<"clicked()";
    socket_session->setThreadFlag(true);

}
```

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qsuXc.png)

I know I am lack of understanding about this but, do I wanna make something nobody does...? I think everyone wants to separate all objects and their methods clearly and communicate via signals or calling functions from delivered object instances...

case 2: ... let me try how you suggested make possible first...

---

I can read C++ code and overall structure, but I don't know why I have to struggle with this, so please help me, dear Guru.

On socketthread.h :

```
class SocketThread : public QThread {

    Q_OBJECT

public:

    QTcpSocket *socket_session;

    SocketThread();
    ~SocketThread(){}

    bool connectToServer(QString, int);
    void sendData(const char*, int, int);
    void run(void);

private:
    QString message;
    volatile bool threadFlag;

signals:
    void changedThreadFlag(void);
    void changedMessageStr(void);
    void setThreadFlag(bool);
    void setMessageStr(QString);

private slots:
    void setStr(QString);
    void setFlag(bool);
    void socketError(QAbstractSocket::SocketError);

};
```

And its implementation is...

```
SocketThread::SocketThread() {
    socket_session = NULL;
    threadFlag = false;
    message = "NULL";

    connect(this, SIGNAL(setThreadFlag(bool)), this, SLOT(setFlag(bool)));

}

...

void SocketThread::setStr(QString str) {
    message = str;
}

void SocketThread::setFlag(bool flag) {
    threadFlag = flag;
}


void SocketThread::run() {
    while(true) {
        if(threadFlag) {
            QThread::msleep(100);
            qDebug() << message;
        } else
            break;
    }
    qDebug() << "loop ended";
}
```

And I have one form which has a button, and I put a clicked() slot of it like this...

[image: the name of the button]

```
void Form1::on_qpushButton__set_white_level_0_clicked() {
    qDebug() <<"clicked()";
    --how can I emit the signal of the one of socketthread from here??
}
```

Now, the mainwindow is like this:

```
MainWindow::MainWindow(QWidget *parent) :
    QMainWindow(parent),
    ui(new Ui::MainWindow) {

    QString addr_server = "223.194.32.106";
    int port = 11000;
    SocketThread* socket_session = new SocketThread();
    socket_session->connectToServer(addr_server, port);


    ui->setupUi(this);
    Form1* form1;
    form1 = new Form1();

    ui->stackedWidget_mainwindow->addWidget(form1);

    ui->stackedWidget_mainwindow->setCurrentWidget(form1);

    socket_session->run();

...
```

I just simply want to emit the signal setThreadFlag of the socketthread from inside of QPushbutton_clicked() slot.
Once the `socket_session->run()` started, I need to change the `threadFlag` by clicking the button by emitting `setThreadFlag()` of one's from the running thread. And I just stuck in here.

Does it possible even?
Or am I doing this all wrong from the beginning?

Comment: @Scheff you meant that I have to start this thread from the inside of the `Form1`?

Answer (score 1):

As mentioned in [this post](https://forum.qt.io/topic/66709/signal-and-slots-emit/3):

> "Emitting a signal" == "calling a function"

So all you really have to do is call the signal function, and all connected slots should be called.

This of course means that the `Form1` object needs a pointer to the thread object, i.e. it needs a copy of `socket_session`. Then you can simply call the signal on the object

```
socket_session->setThreadFlag(your_flag);
```

---

Of course, if the `Form1` have a copy of the `socket_session` pointer, it might as well call `setFlag` directly, if it was `public`.

Answer (score 0):

> I just simply want to emit the signal setThreadFlag of the socketthread from inside of QPushbutton_clicked() slot.

No signal is needed – just call the function.

```
void Form1::on_qpushButton__set_white_level_0_clicked() {
    qDebug() <<"clicked()";
    // --how can I emit the signal of the one of socketthread from here??
    // E.g. this way:
    socket_session->setThreadFlag(true);
}
```

---

To make this possible, another fix is needed:

`socket_session` is a local variable in OP's exposed code.

To make it "persistent", it has to become e.g. a member variable.

So, the constructor `MainWindow::MainWindow()` has to be changed:

```
// Nope: SocketThread* socket_session = new SocketThread();
// Instead:
  socket_session = new SocketThread();
```

and `SocketThread* socket_session;` has to be added to member variables of `class MainWindow`.

To make it accessible in `Form1`, it has to be passed to `Form1` as well.
This could be done e.g. by making it a member variable in `Form1` also which is initialized with a constructor argument (or set from `MainWindow` afterwards).

(I must admit that I never have used the Qt UI builder QtDesigner but build all my UIs by C++ code exclusively.)

---

But, now, another fix is necessary:

`volatile` doesn't make a variable suitable for interthread communication.
(This was used in ancient times before multi-threading started to be supported by C++11.)

However, this is wrong: [**Is volatile useful with threads?**](http://isvolatileusefulwiththreads.com/)

An appropriate fix would be to use `std::atomic` instead:

```
    // Wrong for interthread-com.
    //volatile bool threadFlag;
    // Correct:
    std::atomic<bool> threadFlag; // #include <atomic> needed
```

FYI: [**SO: Multithreading program stuck in optimized mode but runs normally in -O0**](https://stackoverflow.com/a/58516119/7478597)

---

And, finally, in `SocketThread::SocketThread()`:

```
    connect(this, SIGNAL(setThreadFlag(bool)), this, SLOT(setFlag(bool)));
```

is not necessary in this case.
`SocketThread::setThreadFlag()` could call `SocketThread::setFlag()` directly, or even write `threadFlag` itself:

```
    void setThreadFlag(bool flag) { threadFlag = flag; }
```

As I (recommended to) make `threadFlag` atomic, it can be accessed from any thread without causing a data race.

---

**Update:**

After OP has updated the question:

> I just simply want to emit the signal setThreadFlag of the socketthread from inside of QPushbutton_clicked() slot.

The button (created from UI `Form1`) can be connected in the `MainWindow` as well (without using any method of `Form1`):

```
QObject::connect(form1->button1, &QPushButton::clicked,
  socket_session, &SocketThread::setThreadFlag,
  Qt::QueuedConnection);
```

**Notes:**

1. About `form1->button1`, I'm not quite sure.
   I noticed that widgets in UI generated forms can be accessed this way but I don't know the exact details (as I never used the Qt UI builder on my own).
2. I used the Qt5 style of [`QObject::connect()`](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qobject.html#connect-3).
   This is what I would recommend in any case.
   The Qt5 style is verified at compile time. –
   Wrong connections are detected by the C++ type checking.
   Additionally, any function with matching signature can be used – no explicit exposure of slots is anymore necessary.
   Even conversion of non-matching signature or adding additional parameters becomes possible by using C++ lambdas which are supported as well.
   [**Qt: Differences between String-Based and Functor-Based Connections**](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/signalsandslots-syntaxes.html)
3. It is possible to connect signals and slots of distinct threads.
   I used [`Qt::QueuedConnection`](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qt.html#ConnectionType-enum) to remark this as interthread communication.
   (However, I roughly remember that Qt might be able to detect it itself.
   See the doc. for [`Qt::AutoConnection`](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qt.html#ConnectionType-enum) which is the default.

Further reading: [**Qt: Signals & Slots**](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/signalsandslots.html)

Btw. using the Qt signals for inter-thread communication would exclude the necissity to make `SocketThread::threadFlag()` atomic. It could become a simple plain `bool threadFlag;` instead. The slot `SocketThread::setThreadFlag()` is called in the Qt event loop of `QThread`, in this case.

Comment: I sincerely glad to have your detail answer and fix for this, but still I am confusing on this matter: 
```
void Form1::on_qpushButton__set_white_level_0_clicked() {
    qDebug() <<"clicked()";
    // --how can I emit the signal of the one of socketthread from here??
    // E.g. this way:
    socket_session->setThreadFlag(true);
}
```In order to make this possible, Form1 should know have an instance of socket_session which was instantiated from the mainwindow, that's what I don't know now. How can I pass the socket_session instance to this function?

Comment: Even after changing `socket_session` as a member variable, still I am having this error

```
form1.cpp: In member function 'void Form1::on_qpushButton__set_white_level_0_clicked()':
form1.cpp:18:5: error: 'socket_session' was not declared in this scope
     socket_session->setThreadFlag(true);
     ^
make: *** [form1.obj] Error 1
```
without including socket_session in the form1.cpp. I am looping on this matter now...

Comment: Got it: I oversaw that `Form1` but was thinking the button is a member of the `MainWindow` (which it could be as well). In this case, you have to pass the pointer `socket_session` to the instance of `Form1`. To answer this more precisely, I would've to read the ful code. (That's why, it's strictly recommended to expose a [mcve] always.) However, you may find yourself how to do it.

Comment: I really appreciate your answers, I will do my best to resolve my issue with your comments and answers, Thank you...!

Comment: @SinwooYoo I had a look into your upload. The `qpushButton__set_white_level_0` to connect I found in `class Ui_Form1` as `public` member. (This was expected.) Unfortunately, the pointer to instance of `Ui_Form1` is stored as `private` member in `class Form1`. So, the `class MainWindow` hasn't access to it. Unfortunately, I don't know how to overcome this due to my lack of experience with QtDesigner. (In C++, this would be easy to change adding something here or there but this may be overridden when changes are done in QtDesigner.)

Comment: Dear, I glad to have your attention and valuable time for advice. I am working on it to change the logics...