# c++ lock free queue implementation single producer single consumer

Tags: c++, multithreading, lock-free

I tried a lock free single producer-single consumer implementation [link](https://www.drdobbs.com/parallel/lock-free-queues/208801974). The implementation uses list as the underlying data structure and rely on the fact that only producer thread modifies the list.The consumer thread moves the head variable if _head is not equal to _tail.

```
int produced_count_, consumed_count_;
std::list<int> data_queue_;
std::list<int>::iterator head_, tail_;    

void ProducerConumer::produce() {
    static int count = 0;
    data_queue_.push_back(int(count++));
    ++produced_count_;
    tail_ = data_queue_.end();
    data_queue_.erase(data_queue_.begin(), head_);
}

bool ProducerConumer::consume() {
    auto it = head_;
    ++it;
    if(it != tail_) {
        head_ = it;
        ++consumed_count_;
        int t = *it;
        return true;
    } 
    
    return false;
}
```

At any point head iterator points to a value that has already been read.

As there is no synchronized here, I was under the impression that the implementation would not work as the writes by one thread **might** not be visible to the other thread. But when I tested my code producer and consumer **always** produced/consumed the same number of units. Can someone explain how this code can work without explicit synchronization? ( I did not expect changes to tail_ and head_ variable visible to the other thread)

Code to control producer/consumer thread is as follows

```
consumer_thread_ = std::thread([this]() {
set_cpu_affinity(0);
std::chrono::milliseconds start_time = current_time();
while((current_time() - start_time) < std::chrono::milliseconds(150)) {
        this->consume();
    }
    std::cout << "Data queue size from consumer is " << data_queue_.size() << " time " << current_time().count() << "\n";
});

producer_thread_ = std::thread([this]() {
    set_cpu_affinity(7);
    std::chrono::milliseconds start_time = current_time();
    while((current_time() - start_time) < std::chrono::milliseconds(100)) {
        this->produce();
    }
    std::this_thread::sleep_for(std::chrono::milliseconds(100));
    std::cout << "Data queue size from producer is " << data_queue_.size() << " time " << current_time().count() << "\n";
});
```

I ensure that the producer thread outlives consumer thread by adding the sleep_for at the end of the producer thread.

BTW, here is a dissection of the implementation where Herb Sutter discussed what's wrong with it [link](https://www.drdobbs.com/cpp/lock-free-code-a-false-sense-of-security/210600279?pgno=1). But he never talked about whether changes to tail_ and head_ are visible to other thread.

Comment: You're probably less likely to have issues if you use a `std::vector` with atomic numerical indexes rather than `std::list::iterator` which has no atomicity guarantees

Comment: I ran this code many times, with different compiler options and didnt see any race conditions.

Comment: it might happen to work on some or even most standard libraries but there's no guarantee

Answer (score 1):

Debug builds will often "happen to work" especially on x86 because the constraints that puts on code-gen block compile-time reordering, and x86 hardware blocks most run-time reordering.

If you compile in debug mode, memory accesses will happen in program order, and [the compiler won't keep values in registers across statements](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53366394/why-does-clang-produce-inefficient-asm-with-o0-for-this-simple-floating-point).  (A bit like to volatile, which can be used to roll your own atomics; but don't: [When to use volatile with multi threading?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4557979/when-to-use-volatile-with-multi-threading/58535118#58535118)).  Still, cache is coherent, simply loading and storing is asm is sufficient for global visibility (in *some* order).

They'll be atomic because they're `int` sized and aligned, and the compiler does them with a single instruction because it's not a DeathStation 9000.  Naturally aligned `int` loads and stores [are atomic *in asm* on normal machines like x86](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36624881/why-is-integer-assignment-on-a-naturally-aligned-variable-atomic-on-x86), not guaranteed in C.  (https://lwn.net/Articles/793253/)

If you only test on x86, the hardware memory model gives you program-order plus a store buffer, so you effectively get the same asm as you would with `std::atomic` `memory_order_acquire` and `release`.  (Because of debug builds not reordering between statements).

C++ undefined behaviour (including this data-race UB) does *not* mean "guaranteed to fail or crash" - that's what makes it so nasty and why testing isn't sufficient to find it.

Compile with optimization enabled and you might see big problems, depending on compile-time reordering and hoisting choices.  e.g. if the compiler can keep a variable in a register for the duration of a loop, it'll never re-read from cache/memory and never see what the other thread stored.  Among other problems.  [Multithreading program stuck in optimized mode but runs normally in -O0](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58516052/multithreading-program-stuck-in-optimized-mode-but-runs-normally-in-o0)

**Code isn't very useful if it only happens to work in "training wheels" mode because you haven't told the compiler how to optimize it safely.**  (By using `std::atomic` for example).

---

I haven't looked in a lot of detail at your code, but I don't think you have any variables that are *modified* by both threads.  In a circular-buffer queue, you often have a `++` increment on a variable that's RMWed by the producer but read-only by the consumer.  And vice versa for a read position.  Those don't need to be an atomic RMW, only an atomic *store* so the other thread's atomic load can see a not-torn value.  That happens for "naturally" in asm.

Here I think you're just storing a new head, and the other thread is just reading that.

In a linked list, deallocation can be a problem especially with multiple consumers.  You can't free or recycle the node until you're sure that *no* threads have a pointer to it.  Garbage collected languages / runtimes can use linked lists for lockless queues much more easily because the GC already has to handle the same checking for objects in general.

So make sure you get this right if rolling your own; it can be tricky.  Although as long as you only link a node into the linked list after it's constructed, and there's only one consumer, you never have visibility of half-constructed nodes.  And you never have one thread deallocating a node that another thread might wake up and continue reading.

Comment: I have used following gcc flags "-DNDEBUG -O3 -Wall -Wextra -fstrict-aliasing" and still it worked as expected.

Comment: @user14757101: ok.  Are your produce and consume functions in a separate file from their caller?  Without `-flto` or `-fwhole-program`, cross-file inlining (other than via #include) can't happen, which would give you a compiler memory barrier around every call.  (on x86, that's like atomic_thread_fence(mo_acq_rel)).  Or if not, then I guess you got lucky, with other functions called in between happening to get the compiler to store and reload global vars.  And compile-time reordering didn't happen I guess.

Comment: Everything except the main function is in the same file. Is my understanding correct that updates to head_ and tail_ variables might not be visible across threads as they are not synchronized and It just happens to work in this case?

Comment: @user14757101: Yes, this is a huge pile of undefined behaviour.  I'm not sure enough of the internals of `std::list` to say if making `head_` and `tail_` both `std::atomic<std::list<int>::iterator>` would be sufficient.  (Or even if an iterator is a single pointer.  (If it's larger, atomic writes and reads are expensive (e.g. `lock cmpxchg16b` on x86-64 just to read or write 16 bytes atomically) and might not even be lock-free (if larger, or if the implementation uses locking for 16-byte objects)).

Answer (score 0):

The article says:

> Another issue is using the standard std::list. While the article
> mentions that it is the developer responsibility to check that the
> reading/writing std::list::iterator is atomic, this turns out to be
> too restrictive. While gcc/MSVC++2003 has 4-byte iterators, the
> MSVC++2005 has 8-byte iterators in Release Mode and 12-byte iterators
> in the Debug Mode.

That is your responsibility to ensure that iterators are atomic. That is not the case for `std::list`. There are no guarantees on the read/write operations from different threads unless you explicitly specify data as atomic. However even if "undefined behavior" means "nasal demons", there is nothing wrong if these demons are observed as a consistent synchronization.