# C++/C check and toggle a bool in single instruction

Tags: c++, boolean, boolean-logic, boolean-expression

I am looking for a way in C++ `bool` type (or possibly C `int`), that checking (if statement) and editing the `bool` in a single instruction. Google search got me nowhere, maybe I am using wrong keywords.

**Example:**

```
bool valid;
.
.
.
if(valid){
    valid = false;
    // do stuff
}
```

For now, I use `std::atomic<bool>`, but still, `if(valid)` and `valid = false` are different instructions, and in a multi thread environment, there are things getting in between. Is there a way to make this 2 operations atomic, without using mutexes ?

I am using GCC 11 / G++ 11.

Comment: [std::atomic_compare_exchange()](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/atomic/atomic_compare_exchange)?

Comment: If you're programming in C++ then you're programming in C++ and only C++. Please don't tag (or mention) other unrelated languages.

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude Thanks for your input. There could be a way to do this with C integers (bit operators etc.). I mentioned this in the question.

Comment: `int`s and `bool`s are not atomic (in both C and C++), and attempting to access them from several threads would cause UB, no matter how clever the bit operations are.

Comment: @Scheff'sCat I am using this code above, in a really frequently visited bottleneck part. Is that code introduce any expense in the manner of CPU cycles ? It is not clear in the docs.

Comment: @HolyBlackCat What about `std::atomic<int>` and `std::atomic<bool>` ?

Comment: Those are ok...

Comment: A synchronized communication between threads comes always to a certain performance price. You have to pay it by any chance or would introduce a data race. AFAIK, atomics are the cheapest kind of thread sync. If you are not using multiple threads (or valid is used (read/written) in one thread only), then just leave it as is... (and forget about atomics).

Comment: @Scheff'sCat Unfortunately, I have more than 10 threads, accessing that variable many many times :) So any clever way of atomizing (is this a word ?), I would welcome with open arms.

Comment: FYI: [SO: Multithreading program stuck in optimized mode but runs normally in -O0](https://stackoverflow.com/a/58516119/7478597) ;-)

Comment: @Scheff'sCat It seems there is a type `std::atomic_flag`. It seems a bit lighter than `std::atomic<bool>`. Unfortunately it doesn't have method like `test_and_clear`. But it does have `test_and_set`. Maybe if I switch the logic of my `if` statement, I could use this.

Comment: If in doubt have a look onto the assembly code e.g. in [Compiler Explorer](https://godbolt.org/). Sometimes, it's surprising how different C++ code is compiled into to the exact same binary code...

Comment: If your program might run on different CPU types in the future (e.g. x86, ARM and Sparc), you either have to use a very tricky programming or consider some performance loss because there are CPUs that do not support atomic access to variables at all.

Comment: who sets the flag? The best synchronization between many threads is no synchronization or as little as possible, so you need to consider the whole picture. Maybe a condition variable would help

Comment: @463035818_is_not_a_number This code behaves like an entry invalidator for this concurrent DB I wrote. synchronization is necessary, the implementation details are up for debate however.

Comment: This doesn't have a whole lot to do with the higher level language but everything to do with what the underlying CPU is capable of. You can't do it in a single instruction if there is no "check and modify" instruction available, obviously. There exists no C++ library which can re-design the CPU ISA.